# Type 'string' is not comparable to type 'unknown[]'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am following a tutorial where I am creating a custom pipeline in angular. I am taking in arguments and using switch to decide how to convert the miles entered.

Error I get when I hover over case values of 'km','m','cm':

```
Type 'string' is not comparable to type 'unknown[]'
```

html code:
`

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col">
      <label>Miles</label>
      <input (input)="onMilesChange($event)" />
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <label><b>Kilometers</b></label>
      {{miles|convert}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

`

`

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'convert'
})
export class ConvertPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: unknown, ...args: unknown[]): unknown {

    if(!value){
      return ''
    }
    switch(args){
      case 'km':
        return value * 1.60934
      case 'm':
        return value * 1.60934 * 1000
      case 'cm':
        return value * 1.60934 * 1000 * 1000
        default:
          return value
    }
    return <number>value*1.60934;
  }

}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the docs: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#using-the-pipetransform-interface

Your transform function signature is unnecessarily complex - you only need value and unit.

```ts
@Pipe({
  name: 'convertToMetricUnit',
})
export class ConvertPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number, targetUnit: 'km' | 'm' | 'cm'): number {
    switch (targetUnit) {
      case 'km':
        return value * 1.60934;
      case 'm':
        return value * 1.60934 * 1000;
      case 'cm':
        return value * 1.60934 * 1000 * 1000;
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
{{ 10 | convertToMetricUnit: 'km' }}
```